# Tomcat: /etc/init.d/tomcat dont exist and monit dont work

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, monit

Im trying to build monit with tomcat in ubuntu, but I have two problems.

I cant find the pid file, and "/etc/init.d/tomcat" doesnt exist

How can I did it?

This is my code in monit:

```
check process tomcat with pidfile "/var/run/tomcat/tomcat.pid"
  start program = "/usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh" as uid tomcat gid tomcat
  stop program = "/usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh" as uid tomcat gid tomcat
  if failed port 8080 then alert
  if failed port 8080 for 5 cycles then restart
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Tomcat seems not to create a pidfile regardless of config. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/atushi/6315474) for a hint on how to convince Tomcat to create one.
2. If you are on Ubuntu >= 15.04 you should have `systemd` present (see [this wiki entry](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/systemd/)). Therefore start/stop should be `systemctl start tomcat` and `systemctl stop tomcat` (or `tomcat.service`).

If you cannot get your Tomcat to creating a pidfile, you can also use [matching](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Process) instead of a pidfile (but I would always recommend a pidfile!).

The rest seems okay with a little limitation: If you start using `systemctl` to start/stop services you need to have superuser privileges to do so. You than omit the `as uid tomcat gid tomcat` part of the `start/stop program`.

---

*edit 2019-11-02, 14:00 UTC*:

My config would look like this:

```
check process tomcat with pidfile "/var/run/tomcat/tomcat.pid"
  start program = "/bin/systemctl start tomcat.service"
  stop program = "/bin/systemctl stop tomcat.service"
  if failed port 8080 then restart
  if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then unmonitor
```

Comment: Hi @boppy! Thanks for u answer :) I did what u comment on the first point and it works. But I have a doubt, int my code I should delete "as uid tomcat gid tomcat"  and only leave "start/stop program=... /route/.." , no?

Comment: It feels a bit weird at first sight, but it makes sense: systemd will start your tomcat with a non-root-user. But to do so, it needs superuser rights. So **the call** to `systemctl` is done using a superuser while **the result** is a binary launched as non-superuser. - I also added a possible final config that should work.

Comment: Thank u too much @boppy :)